# What Dahon adjustable handlebar stem would suit my Dahon MU XL Sport Bike

Tags: stem

I own Dahon Mu xL Sport foldable bike and use it for exercise. I have a back problem and would like to fit a Dahon adjustable stem to keep my riding position more upright. I have tried adjusting the saddle height but am still sore after cycling.

Can you let me know, please:

- what Dahon stem would suit
- what is the likely cost
- I'm living in Ireland and finding it heard to locate a stockist. Can you suggest any store.

Comment: unless you're actually going to move the stem around, i suggest finding a non-adjustable stem that puts the bars exactly where you want them

Comment: Do Dahon bikes even have stems? Thought they had an adjustable handlebar ‘mast’. Could you include a picture of your bikes handlebar?